# php, Record Fetch from two tables

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

we have two tables name "students" AND vouchers. we create the voucher of the fee and display voucher, and we also want to display the roll no of that particular student which was we create voucher, but we can't get the roll any of student table ... we got error,[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVumV.png) I've added the code below

```
      <?php if(isset($_GET['session_id'])):?>
        <?php $student_session= $_GET['session_id'];?>
        <?php 
        $stu = "select *  from students where 
        session_id='$student_session'";

                $run_stu = mysqli_query($con,$stu);
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($run_stu)){
                $stu_id = $row['student_id'];
                $stu_roll = $row['roll_no'];
                $stu_name= $row['s_name'];
            ?>

                <?php

if (isset($_POST['many_voucher'])){

    $student_roll = $_GET['roll_no'];

    $student_session_post = $_GET['session_id'];
    $fee_date = $_POST['fee_date'];
    $adm_fee = $_POST['adm_fee'];
    $reg_fee = $_POST['reg_fee'];
    $tution_fee = $_POST['tution_fee'];
    $lab_fund = $_POST['lab_fund'];
    $misc_dues = $_POST['misc_fund'];
    $others = $_POST['others'];
    $total_amount = $_POST['total_amount'];
    $due_date = $_POST['due_date'];
    $remarks = $_POST['remarks'];



    $query = "Insert INTO vouchers(session_id,roll_no,fee_month,adm_fee,reg_fee,tution_fee,lab_fund,misc_dues,other_dues,total_amount,due_date,remarks)
            VALUES('$student_session_post','$student_roll','$fee_date','$adm_fee','$reg_fee','$tution_fee','$lab_fund','$misc_dues','$others','$total_amount','$due_date','$remarks')";
                    if(mysqli_query($con,$query)){

                //echo "<script>alert('Run')</script>";

    }else{
        echo"query failed";
        }
    }
```

?>

Comment: can you specify the lines on which these errors are occuring in the above code

Comment: $student_roll = $_GET['roll_no'];

Comment: i'm added pic also , see that, thanks

Comment: looks to me like the table `students` does not contain a column named `roll_no`. what do you get if you add `while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($run_stu)){var_dump($row);`  ?

Comment: no , students table have roll_no feild

Comment: Why are $student_session_post and $student_roll = $_GET not $_POST as the others

Comment: check the url bro. From where are you getting the roll_no from $_GET

Comment: @Mohsin what do you get if you add to to while loop: `while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($run_stu)){var_dump($row);`   ?

Comment: Please do not use your current code in a production environment. You have opened yourself up to SQL injection attack. Just google sql injection to read a multitude of articles about it.

Comment: @ehymel look at the url in the browser in the screenshot, safe to say that's a dev computer

Comment: array(48) { [0]=> string(2) "17" ["student_id"]=> string(2) "17" [1]=> string(8) "MIT17002" ["roll_no"]=> string(8) "MIT17002" [2]=> string(12) "Waqas Hafeez" ["s_name"]=> string(12) "Waqas Hafeez" [3]=> string(4) "0001" ["reg_no"]=> string(4) "0001" [4]=> string(4) "Male" ["sex"]=> string(4) "Male" [5]=> string(10) "0000-00-00" ["dob"]=> string(10) "0000-00-00" [6]=> string(12) "Fedral Board" ["uni_board"]=> string(12) "Fedral Board" [7]=> string(12) "0317-0011200"

Comment: @Mohsin you are only getting generate and session_id from $_GET

Comment: oh oki, then it must be the $_GET variable. @Mohsin what do you get if you add `var_dump($_GET);`  ?

Comment: nothing to show anything var_dump($_GET);

Comment: I'm just getting the roll no of the student from students table and post into vouchers table for the purpose of transparency

Comment: What happens if you replace $student_roll = $_GET['roll_no']; with $student_roll = $stu_roll;

Comment: @hanshenrik - I did see that, but would hate to see this used in production, and not everyone seems to know about the problem. Just making sure!

Comment: @ehymel ,i know about open URL , but i'm a beginner, and i have avoid this practice after feel professional in php

Comment: Great that the solution has been found. However, you prolonged this thread because the solution was already here in one of the comments above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with this

```
<?php  if(isset($_POST['many_voucher'])){

    $student_roll = $stu_roll;
}
  ?>
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\erp\generate-vouchers.php on line 224

Comment: if (isset($_POST['many_voucher'])){

if (isset($_GET['roll_no']{
    $student_roll = $_GET['roll_no'];
} else echo "roll_no doesn't exist";

Comment: Not working answer if (isset($_POST['many_voucher'])){

if (isset($_GET['roll_no']{
    $student_roll = $_GET['roll_no'];
} else echo "roll_no doesn't exist";

Comment: i forgot 2 brackets,sry about that, i edited the post

Comment: we are already adding brackets, but now, nothing happens for all,

Comment: fetch roll_no from student table and post in voucher table , how we get roll_no , and post into voucher table? our code scenerio is correct or not?

Comment: if $stu_roll = $row['roll_no']; is the variable that you are fetching it has nothing to do with $_GET ,$_GET recives parametars that you pass by url .If that is the case then your  $student_roll = $stu_roll. Try with that.

Comment: no, i'm just fetch roll_no from database table students

Comment: kindly guide me if possible ? how to get roll_no from students table and post into voucher table

Comment: well then get rid of $student_roll = $_GET['roll_no']; and replace with $student_roll = $stu_roll;

Comment: Or suggest one query to resolve my problems, regards

Comment: It's Working @alex Bro , Thanks